# Как отфильтровать массив через array walk и preg_match

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив $bad, в нем содержатся запрещенные слова, есть массив $divs который не должен содержать элементы массива $bad, я пробую фильровать при помощи array_walk, если есть совпадение результат 1, если нет, то 0. Как заставить array_walk возвращать корректные значения ?

```
    function test(&$item1,$key,$prefix)
{
    if (!preg_match($item1, $prefix))

{
    return true;
}

}

$bad = array('/soc/','/comm/','/share/');

     foreach($divs as $temp)
     {
         echo array_walk($bad, 'test', $temp);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Находите попросту расхождения массивов.

```
$result = array_diff($divs, $bad);
```

Получите в $result те значения $divs которых нет в $bad

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$divs = array('str1','str2','/soc4353453','/comm/','/share/');
$bad = array('soc','comm','share');

$good = [];

foreach($divs as $temp)
{
    foreach($bad as $bad_item){
        if(strripos($temp, $bad_item)){
            goto end;
        }
    }
    $good[] = $temp;
    end:
}

print_r($good);
```

Comment: в таком случае comm1 к примеру пройдет как допустимый, не отфильтруется по регулярному выражению

Comment: @Юрий оно никак не отфильтруется по регулярному выражению если в прег мач пихать массив вместо строки. А чтоб отфильтровалось - запусти доп цикл и подставляй значения из массива а не его сам.